# reload the page using ajax in order to create a live chat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I have this code:

```
<?php require_once("config.inc.php"); ?>
<?
ob_start();
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
// do nothing here
} else { ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Live chat</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<font color="white" size="+3"><b>You are not logged in! <br />
Log in and start chatting!</b></font>
</body>
</html>
<?php exit(); }
ob_flush();
?>







<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_description ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta_keywords ?>" />
<title><?php echo $site_name; ?> | Live chat</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.png" >
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    body { margin:0;padding:0;  background-image:url(images/background.jpg);  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#lolmesazhet").load("mesazhetnechat.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#lolmesazhet").load("mesazhetnechat.php");
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="500px" bgcolor="#000000" >
    <?php include 'headerchat.inc.php'; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td width="500px"  align="left" valign="top" style="padding:20px 5px 20px;">
<?php
if($_POST['submit654']) {

$result128 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$_SESSION[myusername]'");
$row128 = mysqli_fetch_array($result128);

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tirane");
$todaydate3 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO chat (id, derguesi, dhoma, mesazhi, ora) VALUES (NULL, '$row128[id]', 'Main room', '$_POST[mesazhi]', '$todaydate3')");
}
?>
<table width="470px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="50px" valign="middle" colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="320" height="339px" valign="top" style="padding:3px;">
<div style="width:320px; height:339px; overflow-y:auto;">
<?php
$result73 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM chat WHERE dhoma = 'Main room' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row73 = mysqli_fetch_array($result73))
  {

$result127 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '$row73[derguesi]'");
$row127 = mysqli_fetch_array($result127);
?>
<table width="320px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="left"><font color="white" size="4"><b><?php echo $row127['username']; ?></b></font></td>
    <td width="170" align="right"><?php echo $row73['ora']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
<font color="white"><?php echo $row73['mesazhi']; ?></font>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</td>
    <td width="150" height="450px" rowspan="2" valign="top" style=" padding:3px;  border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;">
    <div style="width:150px; height:450px; overflow-y:auto;">
    <font color="#FFFFFF" size="+2"><b>Online users:</b></font><br /><br />
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE verifikuar='po' AND online = 'po'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          { ?>
                <font color="#FFFFFF"><b><?php echo $row['username']; ?></b></font>  <br />
          <?php }
        ?>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="50px" valign="middle" style="border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF; padding:3px; border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;">
<form action="" method="post" name="comesazh">
<textarea name="mesazhi" cols="35" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
<br /><input type="submit" name="submit654" id="submit654" value="Send" style="border-radius:0px; border-size:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#ffffff; border-width:thin; background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; height:26px; width:60px;  font-size:16px;" />
</form>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to reload that page using ajax in order to create a live chat and if yes, how to do it.
I tried many ways like reloading just a part of it using `$.load` function but it does not work. Then I tried to `$.load` all the page, but still did not work. After a lot of silly efforts, I gave up.

Comment: paste the code here - not in paste bin. and also a fiddle, if u can.

Comment: the fiddle is not possible because that code works with sessions. fiddle will display nothing...

Comment: You're using `mysqli` which is good, but you're **completely** ignoring the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method for [properly escaping SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, it's 2013. You're not supposed to open Notepad and start slamming out code like this where model, view and controller concerns are all smashed into the same file like some kind of code stew. If you [learn a popular framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) you'll be far more productive.

Comment: this is not my problem. I need to turn that into a chat page and I did read that could be done by adding reload page function made with ajax. I would like a small example because I tried many times and did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to have the chat box update without reloading the page.
Chat page that you have:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}, 5000);
</script>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>This should be your chat box</h2></div>
```

Response.php

```
<?php
//do the while loop for the amount of chat you want to see
//example

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.'<br/>'; // Print out $i
}

?>
```

This will update the chat box every 5 seconds with the most recent chats. Give it a shot

Comment: Thanks tried it but still did not work. Anyway, thanks for the help. I will try it again :/ Hope it works next time :)

Answer (score 0):

> If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the document does not contain an element with id="result" — the Ajax request will not be sent.

From jQuery.load manual. I can't see element with ID "lolmesazhet" in your code. Or I'm missing something.