# Refresh chatbox without refreshing page

Tags: refresh, chat

I'm working on a chat application for my website and everything has been coded (in php).
But I need the chatlog to refresh (once every second or so...) how can I do this?

Comment: I want this to be done using ajax, in that post the answers all use php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350193/reload-the-page-using-ajax-in-order-to-create-a-live-chat